# shell_exec('dig ~') returns null, but shell_exec('whoami') does not

Tags: php, dig

I am trying to return dig output to html using PhP but my

```
$output = shell_exec('dig txt 48.60.191.107.query.senderbase.org');
echo '<pre>$output</pre>';
```

command comes up NULL.
as I test I tried 'whoami' and it returned www which is correct.

How do I get `shell_exec()` to output a dig query?

Comment: Is it installed? Did you test from the shell? Is its location in the path? What do the error logs say? Did you capture `stderr` yet with `2>&1` etc.?

Comment: @mario I keep getting 'command not found'?

Comment: Well, that doesn't leave much room for interpretation. Install it.

Comment: @mario but I can run the dig command at the command line on the same server just fine. It's doesn't like sudo either.

Comment: You still haven't answered:  Is its location in the path?

Comment: My guess is that www (apache user) doesn't have permissions to run the command. Try adding www to `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @EternalHour  same command not found after adding ->  www ALL=(ALL) ALL  to sudoers

Comment: I gave it the full path to dig and it worked. But curious why.